# How can I prevent booting from media devices?

Tags: usb, centos, boot

first of all, I deeply apologise because of my silly question. The thing is that I am learning about hardening. I have VMware workstation 12, and I've created a VM CentOS 7 machine (to be integrated in a MySQL virtual server).

What I need is to prevent booting the VM from media devices (USB and CD/DVD.... by the way, is it possible to boot from VGA or HDMI ports?). I've searched too long in the web, and I've found that it is possible by configuring it in the BIOS/UEFI. The thing is that I don't understand how to do it... Is it possible to reach it from the virtual machine? (if yes, how?). I do not want to disable USB, nor remove USB drivers (let's say, for example, that I do want it to make periodical back ups). I only want to disable USB booting, everything else from peripherical devices can be drivers removed, because they do not serve any function to the system.

Comment: Could you write in simple words what do you want to protect and from what threat?

Comment: I think you are confused about what you want to achieve. A VM cannot directly boot from perpherals of the host computer without configuration through the VM software. You'll just have to isolate the VM and use user permissions to secure the VM configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the BIOS from the VM. The BIOS can only be accessed at the machine startup usually by pressing the "esc" key or either f2 or f12 key as soon as you power it on.

Once you have access to the BIOS, there is the option to disable USB booting. Usually you should find it in "Startup options" but your might be different.

Comment: How do you know OP did not mean the BIOS of the VM?

Answer (score 0):

It's been my experience that there are boot options in KVM/Hyper-V/ESX/ESXi that allow the VM to boot into it's own BIOS. You can then disable things in the BIOS as you like. :)

If you are talking about the VM itself accessing the host's bios, I suppose it could be possible, but you'd have to jump through a lot of hoops to get there :)

Comment: Usually the option is buried in the VM configuration somewhere, just to clarify.